# How to check the JSON Serialization provider that is used by my JEE8 app

Tags: serialization, jakarta-ee, payara

I am searching a way to log the JSON Serialization provider name that's used by my application (is it Moxy or Jackson or Json-b) to be sure that when I configure one of these providers I have a way to check that my config is working.
I am deploying on both payara 4 and 5

Thank you for any help.